# are there any posters available with all astronauts/cosmonauts?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight

The only poster imaging all astronauts at that time I am aware is the one
created by NASA in 1967. Are there any follow ups with meanwhile 550 space travellers?

Answer (score 2):

I know of no posters that show all the world's astronauts.  The NASA Space Flight Awareness [page](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/sfa/sfa-posters) has some down-loadable posters going back to the  days of a crowded Shuttle Astronaut Office before the Columbia accident, and as recent as 2015.  As well as the occasionally amusing ISS Expedition crew posters.

[image]

Comment: I suspect one of the amusing posters you refer to is the [Expedition 45 poster](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/exp_45_sfa_crew_poster_low.pdf) (PDF file) which every space junkie needs to see...